# Windows 7 keeps making device plugin sound

Tags: windows-7

I have windows 7 and while just doing regular computer tasks, it makes the Device plugged in and device unplugged sounds at random. It does this whether my portable hard drive is plugged in or not and windows doesn't show the dialogue that normally appears when you plug a device in.

Does this happen to anyone else and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen when infrared or Bluetooth devices come into proximity of a laptop.  I'll typically disable those services because I never use them.

Answer (score 0):

Check your event viewer to see what happened immediately after you hear it. Also look for balloons near the notification area.

Comment: No balloons appear and where do I look in event viewer?